# Reading data or labels of a sharepoint site?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Hello everybody! My problem is that i want to read any data of a SP-Site. So i tried to run a javascript code
with a content editor webart which i added to a Site. There i trie to use:

```
var name = document.getElementById("labelName").value; 
alert(name);
```

But the alert doesn't show me a value. It always shows "undefined".

So I want to ask if it's possible to read the data of labels or something with javascript code in a WebPart or not. And if it's possible how I'm able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, but the id may not be exactly what you expect it to be.

go into the list / library that the element is part of. Right click the column name. In IE you will click properties.

the end of that value is what you want. so for example: 'Percent%5Fx0020%5FComplete'

Here is a good article on it

http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/11/staticname-versus-displayname-on-sharepoint-lists/